# Fixing SSL certificate error in exe compiled with py2exe (or PyInstaller)

Tags: python, ssl, py2exe, python-requests, pyinstaller

I've just finished testing a Python programme which involves logging into a site and requires a CSRF cookie to be set. I've tried packaging it as an exe using `py2exe` and got a socket error. I have the same problem when I try with `PyInstaller`. Googling the Errno I found a few other people with the same problem and so I know the problem is to do with the location of SLL certificates.

This is my `site_agent` class including the logging calls.

```
    class site_agent:
        self.get_params()
        URL = root_url + '/accounts/login/'        
        # Retrieve the CSRF token first
        self.agent = requests.session()
        self.agent.get(URL)  # retrieves the cookie # This line throws the error
        self.csrftoken = self.agent.cookies['csrftoken']    
        # Set up login data including the CSRF cookie
        login_data = {'username': self.username,
                      'password': self.password,
                      'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : self.csrftoken}
        # Log in
        logging.info('Logging in')
        response = self.agent.post(URL, data=login_data, headers=hdr)
```

The error comes at the `self.agent.get(URL)` line and the Traceback shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 223, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 198, in main
  File "<string>", line 49, in __init__
  File "C:\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\autoresponder\b
uild\pyi.win32\autoresponder\out00-PYZ.pyz\requests.sessions", line 350, in get
  File "C:\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\autoresponder\b
uild\pyi.win32\autoresponder\out00-PYZ.pyz\requests.sessions", line 338, in requ
est
  File "C:\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\autoresponder\b
uild\pyi.win32\autoresponder\out00-PYZ.pyz\requests.sessions", line 441, in send

  File "C:\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\autoresponder\b
uild\pyi.win32\autoresponder\out00-PYZ.pyz\requests.adapters", line 331, in send

requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:336: error:0B084002:x509
certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

Does this mean that the problem is in `requests.adapters`?

If so, can I just edit it in my installed Python packages to look for cacert.pem somewhere else, rebuild my exe with `py2exe` or `PyInstaller`, then change it back in my installed version of Python?

**EDIT**

I now have the programme running after compiling with `PyInstaller` and setting `verify=False` in all `requests.get()` and `requests.post()` calls. But SSL is there for a a reason and I'd really like to be able to fix this error before letting anyone use the tool.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21206079/538284

Answer (score 7):

This can be solved easily if you are using "requests" module.

1) Place the below code in your main python file where "requests" module is used

```
os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = "certifi/cacert.pem"
```

2) Within your distributable folder where exe is present, create a folder called "certifi" and place the "cacert.pem" file within it.

3) You can find the "cacert.pem" file by

```
pip install certifi

import certifi
certifi.where()
```

Awesome.. now your distributable includes the necessary certificates to validate ssl calls.

Answer (score 5):

If using pyinstaller... create a `hook-requests.py` file in `PyInstaller\hooks\` for the requests lib containing

```
from hookutils import collect_data_files

# Get the cacert.pem
datas = collect_data_files('requests')
```

Comment: pyinstaller now includes this hook by default

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer given by `frmdstryr`, I had to tell `requests` where the `cacert.pem` is. I added the following lines right after my imports:

```
# Get the base directory
if getattr( sys , 'frozen' , None ):    # keyword 'frozen' is for setting basedir while in onefile mode in pyinstaller
    basedir = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    basedir = os.path.dirname( __file__ )
    basedir = os.path.normpath( basedir )

# Locate the SSL certificate for requests
os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = os.path.join(basedir , 'requests', 'cacert.pem')
```

This solution is derived from this link: http://kittyandbear.net/python/pyinstaller-request-sslerror-manual-cacert-solution.txt

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this as well, The `hook-requests.py` provided by `frmdstryr` did not work for me. But this modified one did:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files

# Get the cacert.pem
datas = collect_data_files('certifi')
```