# Twilio Python Module Errors After Compiling

Tags: python, sms, twilio

I have written a simple program that opens a csv file and text all the numbers in it. I am using Twilio ([twilio-python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install)) as a service provider. My code works fine as a python script. However, when I compile the script (using py2exe), the exe file errors. This is the error I receive from the log file....

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "sms.py", line 39, in <module>
 File "twilio\rest\resources\messages.pyc", line 112, in create
 File "twilio\rest\resources\base.pyc", line 352, in create_instance
 File "twilio\rest\resources\base.pyc", line 204, in request
 File "twilio\rest\resources\base.pyc", line 129, in make_twilio_request
 File "twilio\rest\resources\base.pyc", line 101, in make_request
 File "httplib2\__init__.pyc", line 1570, in request
 File "httplib2\__init__.pyc", line 1317, in _request
 File "httplib2\__init__.pyc", line 1252, in _conn_request
 File "httplib2\__init__.pyc", line 1021, in connect
 File "httplib2\__init__.pyc", line 80, in _ssl_wrap_socket
 File "ssl.pyc", line 387, in wrap_socket
 File "ssl.pyc", line 141, in __init__
 ssl.SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:340: error:0B084002:x509 certificate               
 routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

I don't recieve this error when i am using the un-compiled code  (below)

```
  import sys #2 params --- /path/to/contact/file    --- up to 160 char msg
  import csv
  import time

  from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient 
  ACCOUNT_SID = "**************************" 
  AUTH_TOKEN  = "**************************" 
  client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN) 

  sys.argv.pop(0)
  contactFile = sys.argv[0]
  sys.argv.pop(0)
  msg = (' ').join(sys.argv)

  print contactFile
  print " "
  print msg

  info = []
  with open(contactFile,'rb') as csvfile:
   reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for row in reader:
        info.append(row)

  contactCount = len(info)-1

  if contactCount > 0:
     #remove first item from list because its not a value that is needed....
     info.pop(0)

   for i in info:
       print " "
       contactName = i[0]
       phoneNumber = i[1]
       print "Texting " + contactName + "... \n"
       client.messages.create(
       to=phoneNumber, 
       from_="+14782856136",
       body=msg   
       )
       time.sleep(1.5)
    else:
     print("SMSify Error \n The contact file doesn't have any contacts in it.")
```

Any thoughts on what is going on??

EDIT:

Here is my setup.py file

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
sys.argv.append('py2exe')
Mydata_files = [('cacert.pem', ['C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-      
packages\\twilio\\conf\\cacert.pem'])]

setup(
   console=['sms.py'],
   data_files = Mydata_files,
   options={
              "py2exe":{
                    "bundle_files": 1,
                    "compressed": True
                }
         }
 )
```

Comment: An easy solution would be - you can physically place the certificates in your distributable and explicitly pass the certification location in code. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34227183/318700

Answer (score 15):

It's happened because `self-signed certificate` file missed in bundle.

This problem is same for `requests` and `httplib2` modules.

For example, if you have a file named `req_example.py` that using `request` module:

```
import requests
url = 'https://google.com/'
requests.get(url)
```

It works when you run it as `python req_example.py`, but when bundle it, it's not working.

Or if you have a file named `http2_example.py` that using `http2` module:

```
import httplib2
url = 'https://google.com/'
http = httplib2.Http()
http.request(url)
```

It works when you run it as `python http2_example.py` , but when bundle it, it's not working.

To fix that, you have two options, one `bad` and one `good`.

1. Disable verifying SSL certificates:

   To do that for `requests` module:

   ```
   import requests
   url = 'https://google.com/'
   requests.get(url, verify=False)
   ```

   And for `httplib2` module:

   ```
   import httplib2
   http = httplib2.Http(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)
   http.request(url)
   ```
2. Add `self-signed certificate` file to bundle:

   For `requests` module, the file `cacert.pem` is located in:

   `.../PythonXX/lib/site-packages/requests/cacert.pem`

   And for `httplib2` module is in:

   `.../PythonXX/lib/site-packages/httplib2/cacerts.txt`

   For each of them, you can copy it to inside of your project (or just address to it),

   And config `setup.py` for including it:

   ```
   setup(console=['temp.py'],
       # for `requests` module
       data_files=['cacert.pem'] ) # or data_files=['cacerts.txt'] ) for `httplib2`
   ```

   And change your code to using that, for `request` module:

   ```
   import os 
   import requests 
   url = 'https://google.com/' 
   cert ='cacert.pem'
   # or os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = cert 
   os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), cert)
   requests.get(url)
   ```

   And for `httplib2` module:

   ```
   import httplib2 
   cert = 'cacerts.txt' 
   http = httplib2.Http(ca_certs=cert) 
   http.request(url)
   ```

   Or if your `httplib2` version is `0.8`, you can create a file that
   [should](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/source/browse/CHANGELOG#1) named `ca_certs_locater.py`, and define a `get` function,
   that return path of `ca_certs` file.

   ```
   def get():
       return 'cacerts.txt'
   ```

Ok, now for your error, and for `twilio` module, it [use](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/5e42a74889041a5cefd9a50b8629ec5ae4f2cf0d/twilio/rest/resources/base.py#L62) `httplib2`, and  [cacert.pem](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/master/twilio/conf/cacert.pem) of it is in:

`.../twilio/conf/cacert.pem`

So you need to add this file to `setup.py` as described above.

But `twilio` itself has a function with name [get_cert_file](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/5e42a74889041a5cefd9a50b8629ec5ae4f2cf0d/twilio/rest/resources/base.py#L29) that pass `ca_cert` file to `httplib2`.

I think if you using `ca_certs_locater.py` that described above, it also will works for that,
but if not, you have yet an `ugly` option, so  you can monkey patch `get_cert_file` function of `twilio`:

```
from twilio.rest.resources.base import get_cert_file
get_cert_file = lambda: 'cacert.pem'
```

Note that this may an issue for `twilio` or even for `py2exe` or `PyInstaller` .

Comment: Ok. So I added the twilio cacert.pem file in the setup.py file. My setup.py file is posted above. I still get the same error.

Comment: It's not work, because `twilio` want to load it from path of itself, that is `.../twilio/conf/cacert.pem` but that is not existed in bundled package (inside `library.zip` file), try `ca_certs_locater.py` way, and if not work, try `patch` way.

Comment: Ok. So I create the file ca_certs_locater.py and add the get function. Now, am I supposed to bundle that in the setup.py? The answer is slightly vague. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No needs to add the `ca_certs_locater.py` file to `setup.py`, just add this file to inside of your project's root directory, then this file should will automatically added to bundle. 
If this way doesn't work, then try second way: so just add code of above patch (the two lines above) to main file of your project.
Also note that for both of this ways, you should included the `cacert.pem` file to `setup.py`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with twilio and pyinstaller, and was able to fix it by modifying the base.py module in twilio\rest\resources:

```
   def get_cert_file():
 """ Get the cert file location or bail """
# XXX - this currently fails test coverage because we don't actually go
# over the network anywhere. Might be good to have a test that stands up a
# local server and authenticates against it.
  try:
    # Apparently __file__ is not available in all places so wrapping this
    # in a try/catch
    current_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
    #ca_cert_path = os.path.join(current_path, "..", "..", "..",    (old path)
     #                           "conf", "cacert.pem")
    ca_cert_path = os.getcwd() + '\Config\cacert.pem' (my new path)

    return os.path.abspath(ca_cert_path)
```

(I am storing my cacert.pem file in a Config folder off my main script directory)

Answer (score 1):

There should probably be a way for py2exe to bundle up non-Python files, like templates or in this case the SSL certificate stored in cacert.pem. Normally this is done automatically with the MANIFEST.in, but I am not sure how that project handles it. Check the documentation there for more information.